# How to connect two computers using unet audio?

Tags: unetstack

I want to connect two computers using unet audio, so i can transmit and receive on different computers. I am not able to connect two computers. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic steps:

1. Run unet audio on both laptops.
2. Type `tell 0, "hi"` on one laptop. You should hear the transmission. If you don't, you may want to check your laptop speaker volume.
3. You should see a `[1] hello` reception on the unet audio shell running on the second laptop.

You can see a step-by-step example in this blog article:
https://blog.unetstack.net/converting-your-laptop-into-a-janus-modem-using-unetaudio

and also in Section 15.6 of the Unet handbook (although it shows an example using a single laptop both transmitting and receiving -- but the same steps work with):
https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_physical_service.html